# Outputting just value without format from mysql in Python

Tags: python, mysql, json

I'm building API for my app in Python and Flask. I'm trying to output some data in JSON format, however I get weirdly formatted data from my sql query. I would like to see numbers (i.e. field initial_price) as number, not as a Decimal('3.99'), similarly with id and timestamp format.

Also, is it the right way to produce JSON?
This is output from my API:

```
$ curl 127.0.0.1:5000/1/product?code="9571%2F702"
[{'update_time': datetime.datetime(2013, 1, 7, 22, 25, 50), 'code': '9571/702', 'description': '', 'gender': '', 'brand': 'Zara', 'initial_price': Decimal('3.99'), 'image_link': 'http://static.zara.net/photos//2012/I/0/3/p/9571/702/401/9571702401_1_1_3.jpg', 'currency': 'GBP', 'colors': 'NAVY', 'link': 'http://www.zara.com/webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/product/uk/en/zara-neu-W2012-s/341501/883021/', 'current_price': Decimal('990.00'), 'original_category': 'Girl (2-14 years)', 'id': 1623L, 'name': '"I LOVE ..." T-SHIRT'}, 
{'update_time': datetime.datetime(2013, 1, 7, 22, 25, 50), 'code': '9571/702', 'description': '', 'gender': '', 'brand': 'Zara', 'initial_price': Decimal('3.99'), 'image_link': 'http://static.zara.net/photos//2012/I/0/3/p/9571/702/401/9571702401_1_1_3.jpg', 'currency': 'GBP', 'colors': 'LIGHT', 'link': 'http://www.zara.com/webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/product/uk/en/zara-neu-W2012-s/341501/883021/', 'current_price': Decimal('990.00'), 'original_category': 'Girl (2-14 years)', 'id': 1624L, 'name': '"I LOVE ..." T-SHIRT'}, 
{'update_time': datetime.datetime(2013, 1, 7, 22, 25, 50), 'code': '9571/702', 'description': '', 'gender': '', 'brand': 'Zara', 'initial_price': Decimal('3.99'), 'image_link': 'http://static.zara.net/photos//2012/I/0/3/p/9571/702/401/9571702401_1_1_3.jpg', 'currency': 'GBP', 'colors': 'ECRU', 'link': 'http://www.zara.com/webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/product/uk/en/zara-neu-W2012-s/341501/883021/', 'current_price': Decimal('990.00'), 'original_category': 'Girl (2-14 years)', 'id': 1625L, 'name': '"I LOVE ..." T-SHIRT'}]
```

My code is as following:

```
from flask import Flask, url_for, session, redirect, escape, request
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
import socket
import MySQLdb
import urllib

@app.route('/1/product')
def product_search():

[some not important stuff here...]

#creating list of codes with lowest Damerau-Levenshtein numbers
best_matching_codes = []
for k, v in lv:
    if v == min:
        best_matching_codes.append(k)

#returning JSON with best matching products info
products_json = []
for code in best_matching_codes:
    cur = db.cursor()
    query = "SELECT * FROM %s WHERE code LIKE '%s'" % (PRODUCTS_TABLE_NAME, product_code)
    cur.execute(query)
    columns = [desc[0] for desc in cur.description]
    rows = cur.fetchall()
    for row in rows:
        products_json.append(dict((k,v) for k,v in zip(columns,row)))   
return str(products_json)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `json` module. It will output proper `json` from a `dict`:

```
import json
return json.dumps(products_json)
```

---

Using `str` does not produce valid `json`!

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a json library to produce json.

Add to top:

```
import json
```

Change last line to:

```
return json.dumps(products_json)
```